# The api isApiSupported return true but SipManager newInstance still return null in Android native Sip

Tags: java, android

I used Android native Sip api to initialize Sip client.Because I am confused to Sip protocol,I read the android developer document about sip and follow it.When I run my application on Nexus5,it work normally,but when I run it on other device like coolpad, it throw NullPointException from SipManager.The following is my code.For some reason,the username,passwd and domain is private.

```
public static SipManager manager;
public static SipProfile me;
public static String username;
public static String passwd;

public static void initializeSip(Context context) {
System.out.println("initializeSip");
if (manager == null) {
  manager = SipManager.newInstance(context);
}
if (me != null) {
  closeLocalProfile();
}
username = SharedPreferences.getLoginInfo().getModel().getVos_phone();
passwd = SharedPreferences.getLoginInfo().getModel().getVos_phone_pwd();
try {
  if (!(SipManager.isApiSupported(context) && SipManager.isVoipSupported(context))) {
    System.out.println("cannot support");
    return;
  }

  System.out.println("isApiSupported="+SipManager.isApiSupported(context));
  System.out.println("SipManager="+SipManager.newInstance(context));

  SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
  builder.setPassword(passwd);
  me = builder.build();

  manager.open(me);
  SipRegistrationListener listener = new SipRegistrationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
      System.out.println("Registering with SIP Server");

    }

    @Override
    public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
      System.out.println("Register success");

    }

    @Override
    public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
      System.out.println("Registeration failed.Please check Settings.");
      System.out.println("errorCode="+errorCode);
      System.out.println("errorMessage="+errorMessage);
    }
  };

  manager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(),listener);
  manager.register(me,3000,listener);
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SipException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

The following is my logcat. Most strangely,I find that the api isApiSupported return true and the SipManager object is not null.I cannot find the reason about it.

```
1.741 30654-30654/com.dev.goldunion I/System.out: initializeSip
05-18 20:11:41.741 30654-30654/com.dev.goldunion I/System.out:     isApiSupported=true
05-18 20:11:41.751 30654-30654/com.dev.goldunion I/System.out: SipManager=android.net.sip.SipManager@426af938
05-18 20:11:41.751 30654-30654/com.dev.goldunion D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-18 20:11:41.751 30654-30654/com.dev.goldunion W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41692970)
05-18 20:11:41.751 30654-30654/com.dev.goldunion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dev.goldunion/com.dev.goldunion.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:147)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5265)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:760)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                   at android.net.sip.SipManager.open(SipManager.java:180)
                                                                   at com.dev.goldunion.util.RegisterSipAccountUtils.initializeSip(RegisterSipAccountUtils.java:49)
                                                                   at com.dev.goldunion.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5146)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2191)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:147) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5265) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:760) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576) 
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If the `SipManager.newInstance(ctx)` returns null, then SIP is not supported on that device. Not all devices support it, it is down to the manufacturers.

Comment: @ChrisHandy the `isApiSupported(ctx)` return true, the `SipManager.newInstance(ctx)` not return null technically.I can't understand why it return null.

Comment: @Alan.cao I tested on Moto E 2nd Gen and API is supported but VOIP is Not. And `mSipManager get initialized normally (not null). I recon, the null scenario is purely device specific. I would suggest to only write few lines of codes in MainActivity in a new sample project and only test whether a device support API and VOIP.